# Если уточнение в своих кавычках, как быть с запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Запятые отменяются?

> Вода эта с древности считалась не только полезной, но и несущей особую
>   «девственную» свежесть.

А хоть одну можно? После "особую"?

СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вода эта с древности считалась не только полезной, но и несущей особую, «девственную» свежесть.

**Нужна одна запятая,** второе определение поясняет первое, но при этом оформляется как однородное.  Фактически эти определения, как и любые однородные определения, раскрывают одну тему ― в данном случае тему необыкновенной свежести воды.

У Розенталя: 2. Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится: Торчали толстые головни, остатки прежней, сгоревшей бани (М. Г.);

[Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: Орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

**Дополнение**

1) Кавычки вообще, по-моему, не нужны, значение указано в словаре.

ДЕВСТВЕННЫЙ, 2. Находящийся в первобытном состоянии, ещё не подвергшийся человеческому воздействию; **нетронутый, первобытный, первозданный**. Д-ая пустыня. Д. леса.

2) **Возможны три варианта**: 1) **нет запятых**, неоднородные отношения; по смыслу не подходит, получается особый вид девственной свежести; 2) пояснительные отношения **с двумя запятыми** (этот вариант используется редко); 3) пояснительные **с одной запятой** (как при однородных отношениях), стандартный вариант.

Comment: И все же, на мой взгляд, запятую можно и ставить, в зависимости от того, что хотел сказать автор: если имеется в виду какая-то особенная «девственная» свежесть, то запятая не нужна. Если же имеется в виду пояснение, то запятая нужна.

Comment: "Девственный" тут буквально указует на деву: юная особь указала путь к источнику.